# Python Selenium StaleElement Exception

Tags: python, selenium, staleelementreferenceexception, staleobjectstateexception, selenium-webdriver-python

I am looking for a solution to the StaleElementReferenceException that arises when navigating back to a previous page with Selenium.

Here is a sample code to reproduce the error:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
browser = Chrome()
browser.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/')

# Closing the pop-up for cookies
try:    
    browser.find_element_by_class_name('js-accept-cookies').click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass

# Getting list of links on a StackOverflow page
links = browser.find_element_by_id('questions').find_elements_by_tag_name('a')


links[0].click()

# Going back

browser.back()
try:    
    browser.find_element_by_class_name('js-accept-cookies').click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass

# Using the old links
links[1].click()
```

I understood the root cause from similar stackoverflow questions like this one [Stale Element Reference Exception: How to solve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43205160/stale-element-reference-exception-how-to-solve)

However the proposed solution i.e. refetching the links everytime I am navigating back, does not suit me for performance reasons.

Is there any alternative ?

For example forcing the new page to open in a new tab so that I can therefore navigating between the two tabs ?

Any other solution is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
links =[ x.get_attribute('href') for x in driver.find_element_by_id('questions').find_elements_by_tag_name('a')]
driver.get(links[0])
driver.back()
```

Simply get the href value and go back and forth like so. The elements you get from a page get lost on page moving.

Comment: No problem upvote and accept my answer if it helped.